# Spring rest template cannot convert from text/html

Tags: json, spring, rest, resttemplate

Spring rest template throws me the following exeption

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class [Lcom.flightsms.core.dto.AirlineResponseDTO;] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]
```

Here my json response

```
[
 {
  "airlineId": "1",
  "nameAirline": "American Airlines",
  "codeIataAirline": "AA",
  "iataPrefixAccounting": "1",
  "codeIcaoAirline": "AAL",
  "callsign": "AMERICAN",
  "type": "scheduled",
  "statusAirline": "active",
  "sizeAirline": "963",
  "ageFleet": "10.9",
  "founding": "1934",
  "codeHub": "DFW",
  "nameCountry": "United States",
  "codeIso2Country": "US"
 }
]
```

dto class

```
@Data
public class AirlineResponseDTO {
  private String airlineId;
  private String nameAirline;
  private String codeIataAirline;
  private String iataPrefixAccounting;
  private String codeIcaoAirline;
  private String callsign;
  private String type;
  private String statusAirline;
  private String sizeAirline;
  private String ageFleet;
  private String founding;
  private String codeHub;
  private String nameCountry;
  private String codeIso2Country;
}
```

I suspect that the matter is in the converter. I changed the converter configuration but this did not work

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfigSupport extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(converter());
        addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    @Bean
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
        return converter;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that your content-type is `text/html;charset=UTF-8`; I guess you should create a custom `MediaType` similar to `APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8` that is built by using `APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE`

Answer (score 8):

Problem solved.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Comment: It seems is my solution? ;-) Glad to know that help.

Comment: I searched for a solution for over 4 hours. thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that the default converters are not registered by default and an end user has to be explicit about registering the defaults :

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
       MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = 
       new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 

       objectMapper.configure(
       DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,false);

       jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
       return jsonConverter;
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> 
                                       converters) {
            converters.add(customJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            super.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters();
}
 }
```

Moreover please try fix type exception. Content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8] received from the service, the real content type should be application/json;charset=UTF-8

To get all ContentType you can do your custom converter like that:

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = 
new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();        

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = 
new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList({MediaType.ALL}));         
messageConverters.add(converter);  
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```

Comment: Try the second part of my answer should help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RestTemplateBuilders` to create the resttemplate clients. The builders will add the default Message converters.

Answer (score 0):

Using solution above of [user9709261](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51443159/2181576) and [Knight1128](https://gist.github.com/knight1128/66f3e4817ab35c7397fd), I am adding the entire spring rest template from which I was able to consume an html response and get the status 200.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("text", "html", utf8);
headers.setContentType(mediaType);
HttpEntity<Object> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(postResponse, headers);
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(webhookURL);
ApiUrl = new URI(builder.buildAndExpand(urlParams).toUri().toString());

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);

ResponseEntity<String> objectResponseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(ApiUrl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);

Object body = objectResponseEntity.getBody();
return objectResponseEntity.getStatusCodeValue();
```