# Consume Html response using restTemplate

Tags: spring-mvc, resttemplate

I want to consume html response using restTemplate and rerun that response to my html so i can add those content to my html page but getting below error tried so many alternatives but not luck

**I want to consume every type of response and return that as it is to my html/jsp via ajax and render that content in a div.**

HTML (ajax call) --- Spring MVC (rest call to 3rd party) --- application returns html

Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xyz-service/**", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.PUT},produces="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public Object mirrorRest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String url = request.getRequestURI();

        return restTemplate.getForObject("http://xyz-service:8080"+url , String.class);
    }
```

I am able to invoke my serive method that retuning html as respose but getting error

```
"Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.String] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]"
]
```

Comment: Did you checked this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176335/restclientexception-could-not-extract-response-no-suitable-httpmessageconverte?

Answer (score -1):

No you can't. An HTML page is not a json object: REST template is designed to consume RestServices.
You should use a URLConnection from jdk

Comment: There is nothing like a restTemplate cant return an html response. I have come across several cases where restTemplate is used to return html response.

Answer (score -1):

The `Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.String] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8` seems to be due to the fact that `HttpMessageConverter` is not able to read your HTTP response and hence fails with an exception.

Try setting the Content-type to  `text/html`.

If this doesn't work out, try adding your own `HttpMessageConverter`  that can read and convert `text/html`.

The exception seem to have occurred because your request was missing the header parameters.

**Sample code**

```
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + apikey);
        headers.set("Charset", "utf-8");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE);

        HttpEntity<Request> entity = new HttpEntity<Request>(
                    req, headers); //incase if your request have a request body

            try {

                ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class); //if no request body you could simply use headers parameter directly
                logger.info(response.toString());
                return response.getBody().toString();

            } catch (HttpStatusCodeException exception) {
                logger.info("API failed"+exception);
                return null;
            }
```

Also you might want to make sure that you are using Jackson dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```