# Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for content type [application/octet-stream]

Tags: resttemplate, http-message-converter, octet-stream

I am making a simple Rest call as below with no headers in java. But I get this exception message: `Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.things.customer.xcitycustomers.responsemodel.CustomerDetailsGrp1Request] and content type [application/octet-stream]\n\tat`

```
ResponseEntity<CustomerDetailsGrp1Request> response
                = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8089/mock/group1", CustomerDetailsGrp1Request.class, HttpStatus.OK);
```

I am not sure how/why is content type of **application/octet-stream** is being passed. I tried adding content type as application/json in postman header and in request entity too but it doesnot help.
Also tried adding @bean to enable all content type but did not work either.
Any help please!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RestClientException: Could not extract response. no suitable HttpMessageConverter found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176335/restclientexception-could-not-extract-response-no-suitable-httpmessageconverte)

Answer (score 3):

My solution was:
In the mocker server I have not specified the content type, so it was giving me octatte-stream. Once I mentioned the content type as :

```
 "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "../__files/get_users_response.json",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
```

Bingo! It is working.