jackson deserialization issue with -parameter compiler option
I am working on upgrading my java spring project to jdk 17, spring 6. I was getting some error Caused by: org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer$AmbiguousBindingException: Still 2 unbound args at this()/target()/args() binding stage, with no way to determine between them 
To fix this added
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.compilerArgs.add("-parameters")
}

in my build.gradle file and above error fixed, But this introduced some issue in deserialization of POJO.
I am getting below error in my unit tests -
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.kronos.udm.endpoint.host.falcon.client.model.EmployeeDownloadResponseType] and content type [application/json]
org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.kronos.udm.endpoint.host.falcon.client.model.EmployeeDownloadResponseType] and content type [application/json]
    at app//org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:125)
    at app//org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1159)
    at app//org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1142)
    at app//org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:892)
    at app//org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:730)
    at app//com.kronos.udm.platform.rest.client.AbstractRestAPIClient.getResponse(AbstractRestAPIClient.java:115)
    at app//com.kronos.udm.platform.rest.client.FalconRestAPIServiceImpl.doPost(FalconRestAPIServiceImpl.java:407)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.11/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at app//org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:92)
    at app//org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:344)
    at app//org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:233)
    at app//org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:113)
    at app//org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:162)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
    at app/jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy85.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at app//com.kronos.udm.endpoint.host.falcon.client.FalconRestApiClient.hostPost(FalconRestApiClient.java:308)
    at app//com.kronos.udm.endpoint.host.falcon.client.FalconRestApiClient.falconHostPost(FalconRestApiClient.java:296)
    at app//com.kronos.udm.endpoint.host.falcon.client.FalconRestApiClient.falconHostPost(FalconRestApiClient.java:291)
    at app//com.kronos.udm.endpoint.host.falcon.client.FalconHostClient.getEmployeeData(FalconHostClient.java:384)
    at app//com.kronos.udm.endpoint.host.falcon.client.FalconHostClientMicroTest.testAllEmployeesDataDownloadedIsInFileData(FalconHostClientMicroTest.java:342)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.11/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at app//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:76)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.11/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)


If I remove the -parameters from build.gradle then deserialization happen fine and Json response is converted into java object.
I tried to debug the files, the code goes to below method of RestTemplate.java -
    @Override
    public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(RequestEntity<?> entity, Class<T> responseType)
            throws RestClientException {

        RequestCallback requestCallback = httpEntityCallback(entity, responseType);
        ResponseExtractor<ResponseEntity<T>> responseExtractor = responseEntityExtractor(responseType);
        return nonNull(doExecute(resolveUrl(entity), resolveUriTemplate(entity), entity.getMethod(), requestCallback, responseExtractor));
    }

and finally reaches extractData method of HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java class
public T extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        IntrospectingClientHttpResponse responseWrapper = new IntrospectingClientHttpResponse(response);
        if (!responseWrapper.hasMessageBody() || responseWrapper.hasEmptyMessageBody()) {
            return null;
        }
        MediaType contentType = getContentType(responseWrapper);

        try {
            for (HttpMessageConverter<?> messageConverter : this.messageConverters) {
                if (messageConverter instanceof GenericHttpMessageConverter genericMessageConverter) {
                    if (genericMessageConverter.canRead(this.responseType, null, contentType)) {
                        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                            ResolvableType resolvableType = ResolvableType.forType(this.responseType);
                            logger.debug("Reading to [" + resolvableType + "]");
                        }
                        return (T) genericMessageConverter.read(this.responseType, null, responseWrapper);
                    }
                }

the if condition genericMessageConverter.canRead(this.responseType, null, contentType) gives false when messageConverter is MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter so it does go inside with -parameter, but without it the value is true and it goes inside and return the converted object.
my POJO object did not have @JsonProperty annotation on its variables so it applied it but it did not worked. I also tried with @JsonCreater annotation but still it failed with -parameters.
Please help me how to fix this.

Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176335/restclientexception-could-not-extract-response-no-suitable-httpmessageconverte
